# WinForms: Autocomplete in multiline textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

Does anybody know of any solution how to provide autocompletion suggestions (say to help input keywords from a list) for a multiline WinForms TextBox/RichTextBox?

For a single line textbox, this is very easy. Multiline is obviously not implemented directly by Winforms.